# SSRS Dataset get a row based on specific criteria

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, dataset, ssrs-2008, iif

I have a dataset called Box as below:

[Dataset Called Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIY1C.png)

I am trying to rewrite this Crystal Reports command `If {Name} like "Train*" Then
{volume}` in SSRS as =IIf(Fields!NAME.Value="Train", Fields!VOLUME.Value, Nothing) or =IIf(Left(Fields!NAME.Value,3)="Tra", Fields!VOLUME.Value, Nothing) I need to get the last value 9977, but I cannot use *Last* function in SSRS, as the order might change.
Please suggest. 
Thanks.

Comment: A few questions. 1. how do you determine which is the last entry? 2. Do you need the other values in the report or only the last value. If you only need the lest value it might be easier to do this in the dataset query. Also you can replicate the `like` function using `contains`. Something like this `=IIF(Fields!NAME.Value.Tostring.Contains("Train"),  Fields!VOLUME.Value, Nothing)`. Note, `contains` is case sensitive so if you need it insensitive just use `....Value.ToString.ToLower.Contains("train")` or similar

Comment: When you're looking for first or last records it is helpful to add a `ROW_NUMBER` function to your query. Then you can easily identify the records in the report with an `IIf` statement.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, 1. I do not determine which is the last entry, I just specified that I need the last train to be displayed. The datasets order can be changed any time, so I should not depend on the last entry. I need to get the entry with the value of 9977.

Comment: @StevenWhite, This =IIf(Fields!TRAIN_NAME.Value="Train-1,2", Fields!VOLUME.Value, Nothing) does not display anything. I cannot depend on the row_number.

Comment: Something must be ordering the data to ensure the last value is the value you need, otherwise you would be showing data at random.

Comment: @CODECO I'm referring to the SQL function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql. This would add a row number column to your dataset.